# Calculated field in django queryset values

Tags: django

I have a model Client and need to get registration addres in VALUES()

```
class Client(models.Model)
    addresses       = generic.GenericRelation(Addres, null=True, blank=True )        
    name            =models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tel             =models.CharField(max_length=20)
...

def get_addres(self):        
        ''' Returns registration addres
        '''
```

I want to do some thig like this

```
list = Client.objects.all().values( 'name', 'tel', 'get_addres')
```

Please, tell me how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You can't query python values with django's ORM (it speaks SQL to the database, not django models).

You can collect extra information by using the `extra` method on a `QuerySet` with SQL.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra

I'd prefer trying to build this in Python before resorting to SQL. Unless the reason you're using `values()` is specifically to address actual memory issues, I'd just generate the data you need with python.

```
list = [{'name': x.name, 'tel': x.tel, 'address': x.get_address()} 
    for x in Client.objects.all()]
```