# Django - why can't I access dynamically-generated attributes in classes in my models.py from admin.py?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-1.7

Here is `models.py`:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    id        = models.CharField(max_length=14, primary_key=True)
    json_dump = models.TextField(null=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Base, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        setattr(self, 'name', json.loads(self.json_dump)['name'])

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Child(Parent):
    magnitude  = models.IntegerField()
```

In my `admin.py` I would like to configure the admin for Child to have the `name` attribute displayed, so I have the following:

```
class ChildAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Child

    def get_list_display(self, request):
        return ('id', 'name', 'magnitude')


admin.site.register(Child, ChildAdmin)
```

I have to have `list_display` generated on the fly from the `get_list_display` method because otherwise Django throws an error on startup complaining that `name` is not defined in the `Child` model.  However, when running, `name` should be available as it is set in the `__init__` method whenever the object is instantiated from the database.

However, when I try to load the admin page I get the error:

```
Unable to lookup 'name' on Child or ChildAdmin
```

What gives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<class 'app.admin.ChildAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[1]' 
refers to 'name', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'ChildAdmin', 
or an attribute or method on 'app.Child'.
```

The above is more than likely the error message that you are receiving. Abstract classes do not allow you to inherit instance attributes from the abstract class like that. It is looking for `self.name` on the Child class, which does not exist.

The parts of the error we want to look at is:

> ...which is not a **callable**

Nope. It is not a callable, it is an attribute.

> ...an **attribute of 'ChildAdmin'**,

Nope. It isn't an attribute of the `ChildAdmin` class.

> ...or an **attribute or method on 'app.Child'**.

This is the part that is tripping you up. "What gives" is that it isn't an attribute or method of the `Child` class, but it is for the `Parent` class.

What you want to do is:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=14, primary_key=True)
    json_dump = models.TextField(null=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    @property
    def name(self):
        return json.loads(self.json_dump)['name']

class Child(Parent):
    magnitude  = models.IntegerField()
```

Doing this will make the attribute available to the `Child` class from parent. Alternatively, instead of using the `@property` decorator, you could create a function definition called `get_name`. I find the first to be simpler.

The caveat to this method is that it does not save the name at runtime. If you want to do that, you may want to consider Django's signals to do a post_save hook to retrieve the name value and add a `name = models.CharField(...)` to your model.

For clarification, Django does not support this. On startup, the following code runs a check on the list_display property:

```
def _check_list_display_item(self, cls, model, item, label):
    """
    cls=<class 'app.admin.ChildAdmin'>
    model=<class 'app.models.Child'>
    item='name'
    """
    # 'name' is not callable
    if callable(item):  
        return []
    # <class 'app.admin.ChildAdmin'> does not have the class attribute 'name'
    elif hasattr(cls, item):
        return []
    # <class 'app.models.Child'> does not have the class attribute 'name'
    elif hasattr(model, item): 
        ...
    else:
        try:
            # <class 'app.models.Child'>.Meta does not have a field called 'name'
            model._meta.get_field(item)
        except models.FieldDoesNotExist:
            # This is where you end up.
            return [
                # This is a deliberate repeat of E108; there's more than one path
                # required to test this condition.
                checks.Error(
                    "The value of '%s' refers to '%s', which is not a callable, an attribute of '%s', or an attribute or method on '%s.%s'." % (
                        label, item, cls.__name__, model._meta.app_label, model._meta.object_name
                    ),
                    hint=None,
                    obj=cls,
                    id='admin.E108',
                )
            ]
```

As you can see, I have added comments to the code that is run to help you understand what is happening. You are right that the INSTANCE of `Child` does have name, but that isn't what Django is looking for. It's looking for a class attribute, not instance attribute.

So, another way you can tackle this (you won't like this, either) is by doing:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    id         = models.CharField(max_length=14, primary_key=True)
    json_dump  = models.TextField(null=False)
    name       = ''
    other_item = ''
    this_too   = ''
    and_this   = ''

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Parent, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        setattr(self, 'name', json.loads(self.json_dump)['name'])
        setattr(self, 'other_item', json.loads(self.json_dump)['other_item'])
        setattr(self, 'this_too', json.loads(self.json_dump)['this_too'])
        setattr(self, 'and_this', json.loads(self.json_dump)['and_this'])
```

This works. I just tested it. Django will find the attribute on the class.

Comment: Thanks much.  I don't want to use the @property style because I have dozens of such attributes and would like to populate the object dynamically.

Also, in the `__init__` method for Parent, `self` is of type `Child`, as can be verified by adding the line `print type(self)` to the `__init__` method.  So `setattr(self, 'name', json.loads(self.json_dump)['name'])` should be setting the `name` attribute on the Child object.

Comment: @JonCrowell I have updated my answer with WHY Django (Django code included) doesn't like what you are doing and an alternative (hacky) solution. See the bottom of the answer for the update.

Comment: You save my day! Thanks, it worked in Django 1.11 for [annotated fields from the manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682567/how-to-add-a-calculated-field-to-a-django-model/42491803#42491803) class too.

Comment: @MarianoRuiz, at least regarding the annotated fields, to me it looks like an uncomfortable hack. I think it it preferable to solve the issue directly in the admin, by declaring an instance method on `ModelAdmin`. In other places than the admin, the annotated field will already be treated as a property of the method.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display),  change `Parent` model like this:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    id        = models.CharField(max_length=14, primary_key=True)
    json_dump = models.TextField(null=False)

    def name(self):
        return json.loads(self.json_dump)['name']

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

So `name` attribute will be shown.

Comment: My example is simplified -- in actuality there are dozens of attributes and a more complex inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: To simulate a data attribute `name`, the method should be called `get_name`, not `name`.