# How to add variable in Django model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to add variable in Django model and I don't want to save it to database at the same time I want to return this variable to user when calling the endpoint.

this is what i found in the web, but the problem is the variable is not rerun to user

```py
class User (models.Model):
   f_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   l_name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
   full_name = ''
```

How to rerun the full_name to user when he call the api ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a calculated field to a Django model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682567/how-to-add-a-calculated-field-to-a-django-model)

Comment: no, I need to return the full_name to API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is using Django Rest Framework, I don't know how your code is set up, but you'll need to extend your serializer:

add a new field to the serializer: `full_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()`

add a method to the serializer:

```
def get_full_name(self, obj):
    return "{} {}".format(obj.first_name, obj.last_name)
```

NOTE:
there are LOTS of different ways of joining those strings together, using `@property` in your model, fstrings, etc - up to you to choose the most appropriate for your needs (without seeing the rest of your code()

Comment: is there way to change the full_name in viewset Instead of serializer?

Comment: how do you need it to change?

Comment: I need to add prefix to user based on the user info I need to check other filed than change it .

Answer (score 1):

You can define model's [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property):

```
class User (models.Model):
   f_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   l_name = models.CharField(max_length=300)

   @property
   def full_name(self):
       return self.f_name + self.l_name
```

now you use `full_name` same way as normal attribute `user.full_name`.

Comment: how to rerun to user when i call the API ?

Comment: @prg.dev what exactly did you try? Do you get any error?

Comment: where you use the full_name it depend if you use user at template side write {{ user.full_name }} it will return the full name of login user or you use user in view then write request.user.full_name whenever use django default user with extend if you not use django default user write manual

Comment: no error. when user go to ``` http://localhost:8000/api/userinfo ``` I need to return f_name, l_name, full_name... in the API response it give me only the f_name and l_name

Comment: @prg.dev I think you need to add `full_name` to serializer's fields list.

Comment: is there way to change the full_name from viewset ?