# Django : Recalculating mean value in the database after creating a new instance

Tags: django

I have informations about companies presented in a table. One of the field of this table is the mean value of each note the company received ('note_moyenne' in models.FicheIdentification).
By clicking on a button, people are able to submit a new note for the company ('note' in models.EvaluationGenerale). I want the mean value of the notes to update in the database each time someone submit a new note.

Here is my models.py :

```
class FicheIdentification(models.Model):
    entreprise=models.ForeignKey(Entreprise, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    note_moyenne=models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.entreprise.nom_entreprise

class EvaluationGenerale(models.Model):
    entreprise=models.ForeignKey(Entreprise, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    note=models.IntegerField()
    commentaires=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    date_evaluation=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.commentaires
```

views.py :

```
class CreerEvaluationGenerale(CreateView):
    form_class = FormulaireEvaluationGenerale
    model = EvaluationGenerale
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.entreprise=Entreprise.objects.filter(siret=self.kwargs['siret']).first()
        return super(CreerEvaluationGenerale, self).form_valid(form)
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('details-evaluations')
```

Currently I just display the mean value in my table using this

```
def render_evaluation(self, record):
        return (EvaluationGenerale.objects.filter(entreprise=record.entreprise.siret).aggregate(Avg('note'))['note__avg'])
```

but I really don't like this solution as I want the value to be stored in the database, in FicheIdentification.note_moyenne.

I thought about creating a UpdateView class but couldn't manage to link it with my CreateView.

Any help or documentation would be really appreciated, I'm a bit lost right know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, you would not store calculated fields. The usual way is not to store the average, but to use an annotation/aggregation in your query.

To centralize this to your model, you would want to write a [custom model manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers) to implement this, so it can be reused anywhere you use your model without rewriting the logic.

```py
class MyModelManager(models.Manager):
    def note_average(self, **filter_kwargs):
        qs = self.get_queryset()
        # replace `...` with your aggregation as needed
        return qs.filter(**filter_kwargs).aggregate(...) 

class EvaluationGenerale(models.Model):
    objects = MyModelManager()  # override the default manager
    # ... the rest of the model as-is
```

Then you can use something like the following in your view(s):

```py
EvaluationGenerale.objects.note_average(entreprise=record.entreprise.siret)
```

See for additional reference: [How to add a calculated field to a Django model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682567/how-to-add-a-calculated-field-to-a-django-model)

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways of doing it.

Either a listener post_save on EvaluationGenerale ([doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/signals/#post-save)). You'll be able to compute the new average each time a new EvaluationGenerale is entered in DB.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=EvaluationGenerale)
def evaluation_general_note_moyenne_computer_post_save_listener(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    entreprise = instance.entreprise 
    entreprise.note_moyenne = entreprise.evaluationgeneral_set.aggregate(Avg('note')).values()[0])
    entreprise.save()
```

post save listener will only trigger on `instance.save()` and `models.objects.create()` not on `queryset.update()` or `model.objects.bulk_create()`.

Either overriding the save ([doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)) function of your form to compute the average after the creation of the new EvaluationGenerale

```
def save(self):
    instance = super.save()
    entreprise = instance.entreprise 
    entreprise.note_moyenne = entreprise.evaluationgeneral_set.aggregate(Avg('note')).values()[0]
    entreprise.save() 
    return instance
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is as single `FicheIdentification` object per enterprise, you could update the `note_moyenne` field when you save the `EvaluationGenerale` object, like:

```
obj = FicheIdentification(...)

FicheIdentification.objects.filter(entreprise=record.entreprise.siret).update(note_moyenne=obj.aggregate(Avg('note'))['note__avg']

obj.save()
```

Please let me know if it works.

Comment: Where would you add these lines? In the CreateView class associated with EvaluationGenerale? And if so in which function?